# How to override an extension admin template

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, adminhtml, overrides, custom-block

There is an extension which I want to add a little more features on. To achieve that I need to modify two ***.phtml*** files in

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/Orderpreparation/Packing/**Index.phtml**
>   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/Orderpreparation/Packing/**Products.phtml**

I found that ***Index.phtml*** is mentioned in

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/**orderpreparation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_orderpreparation_packing_index>
        <reference name="head">
            ...
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            ...
            <block type="Orderpreparation/Packing_Index" name="onepagepreparation" as="onepagepreparation" template="Orderpreparation/Packing/Index.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_orderpreparation_packing_index>
</layout>
```

On the packing page in the admin, selecting an option in a dropdown list with trigger ***Products.phtml*** to be loaded via **AJAX** and I can't find anywhere of triggering the ***Products.phtml***.

If I want to override Index.phtml should I just create an xml file in layout folder as below:

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/**my_own_xml_to_override_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_orderpreparation_packing_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="Orderpreparation/Packing_Index" name="onepagepreparation" as="onepagepreparation" template="MyOwnFiles/Packing/Index.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_orderpreparation_packing_index>
</layout>
```

Do I have  do anything else to make sure ***Index.phtml*** will be override by my own ***phtml***?

No idea how to I setup to override the ***Products.phtml***?

Do I need to create a new extension in this case?

---

I created my own extension and below is the ***config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_ErpFlyerReminder>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_ErpFlyerReminder>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <flyerreminder>
                    <file>packingflyerreminder.xml</file>
                </flyerreminder>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <flyerreminder>
                    <file>flyerreminder.xml</file>
                </flyerreminder>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <flyerreminder>
                <class>Company_ErpFlyerReminder_Block</class>
            </flyerreminder>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <packing_index>Company_ErpFlyerReminder_Block_Packing_Index</packing_index>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/etc/modules/Company_ErpFlyerReminder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_ErpFlyerReminder>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <MDN_Orderpreparation/>
            </depends>
        </Company_ErpFlyerReminder>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Company/ErpFlyerReminder/Block/Packing/Index.php

```
<?php
class Rycomau_ErpFlyerReminder_Block_Packing_Index extends MDN_OrderPreparation_Block_Packing_Index
{
}
```

Comment: Can you provide config.xml of your module?

Comment: I don't have a ***config.xml*** because I am trying to override that without making a new extension. But if you mean the ***config.xml*** of the extension I am trying to override I can provide that.

Comment: In which file you are defining your file **my_own_xml_to_override_index.xml**? We do it in extension's config.xml file.

Comment: You are right so I updated my question with my config.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your adminhtml layout xml with name **packingflyerreminder.xml**

Create a file **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/packingflyerreminder.xml** with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_orderpreparation_packing_index>
        <reference name="onepagepreparation">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>MyOwnFiles/Packing/Index.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_orderpreparation_packing_index>
</layout>
```

Now create your `phtml` file at **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/MyOwnFiles/Packing/Index.phtml** with your custom code.